# incompatible types: Activity cannot be converted to AppCompatActivity in Flutter

Tags: java, android, gradle, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I got an error after upgrading the **Flutter sdk**. Now it's not building the APK

[image]

This is the **Logcat** result. 
Tried so many things. But none of them not worked for me.

```
incompatible types: Activity cannot be converted to AppCompatActivity
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(new DeviceIdPlugin(registrar.activity()));
```

Comment: found that the error is causing due to the library **device_id ^0.2**. After commenting that from pubspec.yaml, those errors are gone. But still, I couldn't build the release APK.

Comment: You should post your DeviceIdPlugin.java class, or at least contestualize the line 29 of that class, or simply explain what "registrar" is